# Error trying to access xaml "local:" control by name from codebehind

Tags: c#, wpf, class, xaml, visual-studio-2012

This all began as an attempt to have a numeric textbox.  That part is irrelevant but it's why I created the following class.  (By the way, using VS 2012 Express, WPF, C# code-behind).

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Controls;

    namespace Herculese
    {
        public class IntBox : TextBox
        {
            <!-- irrelevant code here-->
        }
    }
```

So far, so good.  I build and this becomes a control which I proceed to use in the xaml:

```
<local:IntBox Name="txtBox_heightft" Width="60" TextChanged="txtBox_Numeric_Changed" />
```

Then in my code behind where I'm trying to refer to the text in the textbox using "txtBox_heightft.Text", I'm informed that "The name 'txtBox_heightft' does not exist in the current context".  This confuses me to no end because if I change "local:IntBox" to "TextBox" in the xaml, it works fine but then of course it's a regular textbox and not my modified version. Do I need to add a reference to the class in the codebehind somehow? This is my first attempt at using a class this way, as I've never needed functionality that wasn't provided by default.

Comment: Does this help http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/3ffb11a7-e1b0-454b-96bf-d2463e89f8ba

Comment: I don't think it does.  'xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Herculese" xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib" x:Class="Herculese.MainWindow" ' is included in my xaml.  I'm thinking the problem is with something I need to include in my c#.  xaml isn't throwing any exceptions.

Comment: Great question, actually. There's no way I would've found that on my own without hours of searching; WPF binding and properties is a black hole.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using Name as a dependency property, you need to use x:Name="txtBox_heightft" as an extension property :)

Comment: Indeed, I just figured that out moments ago while reading through pages upon pages of google results lol the one thing I didn't find was why this is the case when I didn't have to do that for a regular TextBox?